# Regular expression replacement next to number

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this has been answered already. I tried to look for it but maybe I can't figure out how to word my question properly.

Making a little HTML app with a simple regular expression replacement processor.
User can input: text, regex pattern, replacement pattern.
Running into a snag if more than 9 groups are used though and the user wants to place a number beside the group.

**Example:**

- Text: `ABCDEFGHIJ...`
- Pattern: `(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)` (10 groups)
- Replacement: `$10`

This would return `J`, but what if the user wants to return `A0`? How can we replace with `$1 0` without a space in between?

The gist of my code is thus:

```
let input = document.querySelector('#input').value
let regex = eval(document.querySelector('#pattern').value)
let replacement = document.querySelector('#replacement').value
document.querySelector('#output').value = input.replace(regex, replacement)
```

I'm doing a little more error checking and processing than that, but you get the point.

[image: app screenshot]

Comment: `eval(document.querySelector('#pattern').value)` - you **really** shouldn't do this...

Comment: To extend Dai's comment, replace `eval(...)` with `new RegExp(...)` so that the input is treated as strictly regex, rather than as regex by coincidence with JS syntax.

Comment: My issue with using new RegExp() is that I wanted the end user to enter the expressions with the backslash delimited format so they could add the modifiers (i, g, etc).
```eval('/hello/i') !== new RegExp('/hello/i')```

Comment: See [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp](RegExp on MDN); you can pass flags as a second argument, so the best way to replace your usage of `eval()` is to separate the flags from the rest of the pattern string and pass those as the two arguments to `new RegExp()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation sounds somewhat ambiguous. If the user inputs `$10` *and* is using a pattern with that many groups, I'd think the user *likely wants* to use the 10th capture group. If they don't, the user shouldn't have 10 capture groups in the first place.

But if you really want to prevent double digits after a `$` from going to the double-digit capture group, it's a bit hacky, but you can add *another* capture group that matches the empty string, and then replace the user's pattern to remove the consecutive `$\d\d`s, and insert the empty string matcher in between.

For example, `$10` can be transformed into `$1$<nomatch>0`.

I don't see anything clean in [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-getsubstitution) that allows for the escaping of or breaking out of consecutive digits after a `$`, *or* of the guaranteed general replacement with an empty string without tweaking the input pattern.

There's also no need for `eval`.

```js
const value = '$10';

const patternValue = '(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)';
const pattern = new RegExp(patternValue + '|(?<nomatch>)');
const replacement =
  // document.querySelector('#pattern').value.replace(
  value.replace(
    /\$\d(?=\d)/g,
    '$&$<nomatch>'
  );
console.log(pattern);
console.log(replacement);
console.log('ABCDEFGHIJ'.replace(pattern, replacement));
```

But like I said initially, this is a weird thing to want to achieve. A user using `$10` with a pattern that has 10 capture groups *really probably* wants to actually use the 10th capture group.

Answer (score 3):

When you encounter a `$` in the replacement you might:

1. if the previous character was a `\`, treat this a real `$` rather than introducing a capture-group reference,
2. if the next character is a digit, do as you do currently and treat it as a single-digit integer indexing CG references,
3. if the next character is a `{`, find the matching `}` and parse the integer between them and again use that to index the capture groups in the regex.

This way the user can write `$9` or `${9}` but also `${10}`.